# Automorphisms of gerbe

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, category-theory

Let $S$ be a scheme, which we will conflate with a site on $S$ -- the etale, fppf or fpqc site. Let $\mathcal G$ be a gerbe over $S$, i.e. a stack on $S$ fibered in groupoids such that (1) there is some $T/S$ such that $\mathcal G(T)$ is nonempty, and (2) for any two objects $x, y \in \mathcal G(T')$ there is a covering $p: T'' \to T'$ such that there exists an isomorphism $p^*x \cong p^*y$.

I would like to determine the automorphisms of $\mathcal G$. By condition (1), there exists $T/S$ such that there is some $x \in \mathcal G(T)$. Then there is an equivalence of stacks
$$\mathcal G \times_S T \cong \operatorname{Tors}(G, T),$$
where $G = \operatorname{Aut}(x)$. For $p: T' \to T$ and $y \in \mathcal G(T)$, this equivalence sends $y$ to $\operatorname{Isom}(p^*x, y)$.

It should be enough to determine $\operatorname{Aut(Tors}(G, T'))$ for varying $T' \to T$. Since $\mathcal G$ is a gerbe, $\operatorname{Aut(\mathcal G)}$ seems to be a sheaf of groups on the site on $S$. Is this sheaf representable by a scheme? Is it just $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$?

I read that the automorphism group of a $G$-torsor is the form of $G$ determined by the class of the torsor in $H^1(S, G)$. However, the action of $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathcal G)(T')$ need not fix the objects of $\operatorname{Aut(Tors}(G, T'))$ pointwise.

I'm not so familiar with this circle of ideas and I'd appreciate any help.